# Google Maps Asp.net with different automatic searchbox and different markers for them

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

**Context:** I am making a web application on `asp.net`, which have Google maps in it to search the location. I have 2 textboxes named `From` and `To` which works on autocomplete search.

**The Problem:** Only the `To` textbox is creating marker on the map but I want both the textboxes to create markers on 1 map only. Just to tell both textboxes are working with autocomplete search but marker is created only of the place searched by `To` textbox i.e., second one.

**Additional Info:** I don't want different markers for static latitude & longitude. I want different markers based on the search in textboxes.

**The Code:**

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function LoadGoogleMAP() {

                var markers = [];
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    zoom: 8

                });

                var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
  new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8902, 151.1759),
  new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8474, 151.2631));
                map.fitBounds(defaultBounds);

                // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.  

                var places = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('Text1'));
                google.maps.event.addListener(places, 'place_changed', function () {
                    var place2 = places.getPlace();
                    var address = place2.formatted_address;
                    var latitude = place2.geometry.location.A;
                    var longitude = place2.geometry.location.F;
                    var mesg = "Address: " + address;
                    mesg += "\nLatitude: " + latitude;
                    mesg += "\nLongitude: " + longitude;
                    alert(mesg);




                    if (place2.length == 0) {
                        return;
                    }
                    for (var i = 0, marker; marker = markers[i]; i++) {
                        marker.setMap(null);
                    }

                    // For each place, get the icon, place name, and location.  
                    markers = [];
                    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();


                    // Create a marker for each place.  
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        title: place2.name,
                        position: place2.geometry.location
                    });

                     markers.push(marker);

                    bounds.extend(place2.geometry.location);

                    map.fitBounds(bounds);
                });



                // current map's viewport.  
                google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function () {
                    var bounds = map.getBounds();
                    place2.setBounds(bounds);
                });
            }

            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', LoadGoogleMAP); 
        </script>

    //for second textBox named “To”
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function LoadGoogleMAP1() {

                var markers = [];
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    zoom: 8

                });

                var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
  new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8902, 151.1759),
  new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8474, 151.2631));
                map.fitBounds(defaultBounds);


                var places = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('Text2'));
                google.maps.event.addListener(places, 'place_changed', function () {
                    var place2 = places.getPlace();
                    var address = place2.formatted_address;
                    var latitude = place2.geometry.location.A;
                    var longitude = place2.geometry.location.F;
                    var mesg = "Address: " + address;
                    mesg += "\nLatitude: " + latitude;
                    mesg += "\nLongitude: " + longitude;
                    alert(mesg);
                    //});



                    if (place2.length == 0) {
                        return;
                    }
                    for (var i = 0, marker; marker = markers[i]; i++) {
                        marker.setMap(null);
                    }

                    // For each place, get the icon, place name, and location.  
                    markers = [];
                    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();


                    // Create a marker for each place.  
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        title: place2.name,
                        position: place2.geometry.location
                    });

                    markers.push(marker);

                    bounds.extend(place2.geometry.location);

                    map.fitBounds(bounds);
                });



                // current map's viewport.  
                google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function () {
                    var bounds = map.getBounds();
                    place2.setBounds(bounds);
                });
            }

            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', LoadGoogleMAP1); 







        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are creating the map twice.. rather than that, you should create 2 `google.maps.event.addListener` objects, 2 infowindows, 2 markers, 2 `google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed'` listeners in the SAME map.

I have a working example here, hope it helps.

http://jsfiddle.net/5vhwe1hk/